# Make mouse coordinates relative to <canvas> coordinates

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am trying to find where the mouse is on a canvas's 'grid' while maintaining resizability. I currently have the mouse coordinates for where it is on the screen (x and y).

The problem is, the 'scaling' between WebGL (which I am using to draw on the canvas) and the mouse coordinates is different. What WebGL considers to be 10 units to the right from origin is actually considered x number of units from the origin (different screen resolution changes this). This means that when my mouse is over what WebGL considers (10, 10), my mouse coordinates are (100, 100).

**How would I convert the mouse coordinates on the screen to the 'WebGL coordinates' which are used to define a point?**

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868707/transforming-mouse-coordinates-in-canvas-using-fabric-js) but I would like to do it without using Fabric.js.

Comment: Added webgl tag ref. comments

Comment: The default NDC space (without any transforms) is x=-1 on left side of screen, x=+1 on right; y=-1 on bottom and y=+1 on top of screen.

Comment: How would I convert the cursor coordinates in the viewport to what it covers in the NDC space is my question

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583808/3d-math-screen-space-to-world-space/35590403#35590403).

Comment: Or just use basic math:
`mx = (mouseEvent.offsetX / canvas.clientWidth)*2-1` same for y using `offsetY` and `clientHeight`

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The equation you gave me led me to a solution. If you want, create an answer for me to accept!

Comment: @StillLearning here you go, note that you need to invert the `Y` coordinate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert canvas mouse coordinates to relative coordinates in the range of `-1` to `+1`, one first needs to get the relative pixel coordinates within the canvas using [`offsetX`/`offsetY` provided by the mouse event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX).

Then divide this by the actual width and height of the canvas using
[`clientWidth`/`clientHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth).

Having the relative coordinates in a range from `0` to `1` we can now move them into the right range by multiplying by `2` and subtracting `1`.

*Note that in WebGL the up axis is positive `1` so one wants to invert the Y coordinate.*

All put together:

```
var ndcX = (mouseEvent.offsetX / canvas.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
var ndcY = (1 - (mouseEvent.offsetY / canvas.clientHeight)) * 2 - 1;
```

Comment: [The full answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35741551/128511) is harder than it looks but for the normal case your solution works

Comment: Small typo in the `ndcY` calculation. You should be deviding by `canvas.clientHeight` instead of `canvas.clientWidth`.

Answer (score -1):

If your event listener is on the canvas element then the coordinates should already be on the canvas .  Meaning mouse.x = 0 mouse.y = 0 would be at the top left corner of your canvas.

Comment: Looks like this might work. Let me do a bit more testing, but seems good.

Comment: This didn't work. 10 units wide in the canvas was more than 20 units reported by the onmousmove event listener even when on canvas element.

Comment: As mouse.x/y returns the same value as event.clientX/Y it means the coordinates will be relative to viewport not the element. x/y is not supported in all browsers. Ref: https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-mouseevent-x